# Timeline showing badges earned at StackOverflow?

Tags: feature-request, badges, usability, revisions-list, timeline

I mean, there could be a timeline showing you exactly when you've earned your badges in a more intuitive way.

I know you can click on the envelope icon (near your name) and look at the Badges tab but this way you have to click today, yesterday, this week, last week, this month, last month. What about the badges earned more than two months ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What about the badges earned more than two months ago?

You can easily edit the URL (of your recent activity link, at the envelope icon) to show any date range you wish.

Comment: If you try for example: http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/114029?Tab=Badges&StartDate=2009-02-01&EndDate=2010-03-18 you'll get a message: maximum of 90 days allowed. So you can't see when you got all your badges. Nice try though.

Comment: @Leniel: incorrect. The error message is referring to the maximum range, not the earliest allowable starting point. http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/114029?Tab=Badges&StartDate=2009-02-01&EndDate=2009-04-30 works just fine.

Comment: Ok, but this way you can't see when you got all your badges with a unique URL. You have to modify the URL values for each 3 months. The nice thing is that it works. Not user friendly though.

Answer (score 2):

The badges are displayed on your user page in the order they were earned, by date.

The date is not shown, of course, but the order is already there.

Comment: Good to know that Jeff (haven't noted they were in the order you earned them). Maybe when you hover over your badge you could show the date earned along with the information already there. Just an idea.

Comment: Actually the order is by when they were **last** earned.

Comment: What motivated me to write this question is that I'd like to know when I got the badge. Worthless you may think, but I like history anyways. :) Think of it as mean to keep track of your progress based on the time you earned the badges.

Answer (score 1):

Does it really matter when we got which badge? I can't really see much benefit in that. After all, they are there to stay.

Before implementing such a timeline, I would propose making the *reputation* timeline more flexible in terms of selectable date ranges, better zooming and such.

Comment: Just for curiosity I'd like to see when I got a badge. I think your proposed changes are also valid.

Comment: @Pekka - If you're interested, I built a greasemonkey script for a adding the ability to zoom in to the reputation graph a while back - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8672/zoom-in-on-rep-graph/8871#8871