# Isn't Graph Reputation supposed to do something?

Tags: support, reputation-graph

Somehow I thought that clicking the button "Graph Reputation" in a user's profile would create a graph with the reputation of that period. However, nothing happens (the button greys out and that's it).

I noticed this bug since a week or so, haven't seen it reported yet. Using FF 3.6 (latest) on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Graph Reputation` does not graph the reputation of someone, that would be silly (way too obvious). Instead it updates the column of reputation points earned numbers on the right of the graph, and it changes the highlighted area on the graph.

If you use the mouse to click and highlight a time period, the button will do absolutely nothing. But if you manually enter the dates below the graph, the button will update the highlighted area and the points (a twofer, if you will)!...... (although, simply changing the focus away from the date entry text boxes will also achieve the same effect, fwiw...)

(If you have Javascript turned off, the button will also do absolutely nothing, but this is ok, since neither the reputation graph nor the points earned will be visible at all.)

Comment: I like that: *"Graph Reputation does not graph the reputation"*. Indeed. Right. Why would it. So, you tell me, the button is, either way, totally redundant. A hoax, so to speak. It would've been a nice feature to graph Skeets reputation in his first weeks or so (or mine, but that's boring).

Comment: Accepted because it seems true, even though it's rather silly to have a non-working button. The update that the button is supposed to carry out, is redundant: moving focus from the edit boxes does exactly the same.

Comment: @Abel - Re: *"It would've been a nice feature to graph Skeets reputation in his first week or so"* - If you're interested in seeing a zoomed in rep graph over a specific time period, I wrote [a greasemonkey script to do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8672/zoom-in-on-rep-graph/8871#8871). Lets you select part of the graph to see just that period of time. Double click zooms back to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

What it should do, assuming the two dates given are within 90 days of each other, is highlight the part of the existing graph that are between the two dates, as well as update the reputation changes list on the right hand side.

It does not actually create a new graph.

Comment: That's what it does *without* clicking the button, just after loosing focus.

Comment: No, given its label, what it *should* do is update the graph in some way related to the date fields and/or the selected area. The most obvious action, and the one that 99% of users expect on first glance, is to zoom in on the selected dates. The text on the right of the graph is just that, *text*, not a *graph*, and therefore it shouldn't have anything to do with a button that's labeled "Graph Reputation".