# Please remove redundant Graph Reputation button or give it a task to do

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

As long as the button "Graph Reputation" does nothing, it is totally redundant and confusing. My suggestion is to remove it, or to actually have it graph the reputation.

In case someone thinks it updates the graph with the range: [it does not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58634/isnt-graph-reputation-supposed-to-do-something). The graph range is updated by moving the focus from the date-input textboxes or by click+drag the graph itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already has a function. It manipulates the timeframe of reputation changes listed on the right hand side to the value in the textboxes.

By default it does not do anything because the default time frame displayed is the same time frame in the text boxes.

[image: Graph reputation at work]

(Yes, that button does not have the best name ever.)

---

The main argument against the button is that there seems to be no code associated with it. The interface reacts anyway because clicking on the button triggers, as a side effect, the textbox's focus loss event which actually does trigger the action.

**Question: does it make any difference whatsoever to the user?**

Let's see:

- With the button, user #1

  1. Click on date field
  2. Enter date
  3. Click anywhere else to change date (to trigger focus change)
- With the button, user #2

  1. Click on date field
  2. Enter date
  3. Click on button to change date (triggers focus change)
- With the button, user #3

  1. TAB your way (?!) to the *end date* field
  2. Enter date
  3. TAB to the button, press Enter (does it matter the action happens when you tab?)
- Without the button, user #1

  1. Click on date field
  2. Enter date
  3. Click anywhere else to change date (to trigger focus change)
- Without the button, user #2

  1. Click on date field
  2. Enter date
  3. ...
  4. Well? Is this thing loading?
  5. ...
  6. ???
  7. WTF? This thing must be broken. *closes tab*
- With the button, user #3

  1. TAB your way (?!) to the *end date* field
  2. Enter date
  3. ...
  4. (See above)

Comment: Did you try that? It doesn't for me. It does in fact... nothing :) Anything you might expect it to do is done onChange on the text boxes, or by selecting in the graph.

Comment: Please re-read my question, or visit the link. That's exactly what it doesn't do. But because it already happened (the time-frame changes the moment you move focus) we cannot know for certain, can we? Either way, the functionality is void as it is now.

Comment: @Abel; one thing it does do though, is work as a handle for mouse-centric users to trigger the onChange event on the text-boxes (cause it to switch focus), clicking anywhere would work of course, but it gives them a target to click. A mouse centric user would probably use the graph anyway, bit still..

Comment: @roe, @abel, it does work for me. [Proof.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/graph%20reputation.png) I use Chrome Dev for Windows.

Comment: We can all get that result without using the button, whether we use onChange for the textboxes or dragging the right points on the graph (admittedly may take a few tries to get the exact dates).

Comment: I'm sure it does, the thing is, it is a noop, since anything it does do would already have been done, as a result of onChange (or whatever is used) on the text boxes, or selecting in the graph.

Comment: @Grace, @abel, @roe: sure, but _is it obvious enough at first use_ to the user that you need to click on somewhere else after you are done with input? __The button gives a clear target to transfer focus on.__ The fact that the interface reacts to a focus change instead of a mouse click, in this case, is merely an implementation detail usability wise.

Comment: Yes, see my second comment (the third comment from the top). But it still renders your answer invalid.

Comment: @roe, how would a "non-mouse-centric" user give focus to the textboxes to begin with?

Comment: @badp, @roe @Grace: the usability isn't a problem, even for mouse-centric people, if the change is immediate (i.e., onChange, not onBlur) and the button is removed. Well, it won't quickly become as usable as [Google Finance](http://www.google.com/finance?client=ob&q=NASDAQ:MSFT), will it?

Comment: first would probably be a click, to switch from the first box to the second would be tab, and to drop the focus from that one would be tab again, or enter.

Comment: LOL. I'm sorry @Grace, I've never seen anybody TAB his way around in web pages.

Comment: @Abel; onChange usually only triggers when focus is lost, so no, usability is a problem. Making the change immediate though (onKeyDown or whatever), could help. Just don't print errors on invalid input, at least immediately.

Comment: You asked "how would a non-mouse-centric user give focus", I gave you an answer. I'm not saying that people *should* be tabbing or anything.

Comment: @Grace, my point is that a "non-mouse-centric user" would still use the mouse to select the field and type in the date. This is where the button is _required_.

Comment: @roe Enter doesn't trigger those textboxes, though.

Comment: @Grace; does for me, doesn't drop focus though, but it does work.

Comment: @roe: you're correct. Well, why not then either make the text boxes read-only, change the name of the button to "Set yellow range" or ask the smarter programmers of the team to implement onKeyPress or onKeyDown handlers.

Comment: A non-mouse-centric user would select the first field with a mouse probably yes, but would tab away from it (to the second field), like I do. Effectively, you've reached the second field by way of the tab.. :)

Comment: PS: considering usability: having a button having to do nothing is not quite adding to usability (which was why this q. was asked in the first place), but adds to confusion and people asking questions on forums.

Comment: @roe, what about the second field? What are you going to tab to if there is no button down the tab order?

Comment: @roe Could be a browser thing, mayhaps, but enter has no effect here. And I'm not saying that the button doesn't help, badp.

Comment: @Abel: the button does do something. It merely isn't wired the way buttons usually are -- but that's an _implementation detail._ Read my answer.

Comment: badp, re your mod flag: It won't be too long until the chat is up again, just a tiny bit of patience :)

Comment: Sweet, @balpha, I'm hating these comment wars. :)

Comment: I'm sorry if I am appearing hostile or anything. My only point that I wanted to make was that "The button causes the change" (your original answer) is not really addressing the question that states how that is redundant and not observable (which is why it probably attracted that downvote), and that changing the focus of your answer to how it gives a target to click would actually be a valid answer (which you did).

Comment: @Grace: I'm sorry, the problem is I wasn't personally aware of this implementation detail when I first wrote the answer (it still reads okay to me). Effectively, "clicking on the button" still can make things happen :)

Comment: @all: technically the button may sometimes really *do something*, but in the end, we're all users and how we perceive something is what matters. You don't see something happening, so it doesn't happen. Whatever (valid) points are made, the current situaton warrants improvement IMHO (and so far, nothing has convinced me that the button is needed. C'mon, even Google doesn't use buttons in these spots).

Comment: Accepted, partially because of your and other's insights in the comments thread and your willingness to incorporate them in the answer ;-)